# jboss5.1 deployment error 'document base java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base'

Tags: deployment, jboss

Following Exception is come out and troubled when starting jboss.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base C:\mproject\workspace\framework_tmp\WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml does not exist or is not a readable directory

The method of this deploy is carrying out the following description to `C:\jboss-5_1_0_GA\server\default\conf\bootstrapprofile.xml`.

```
    <property name="applicationURIs">
        <list elementClass="java.net.URI">
            <value>${jboss.server.home.url}deploy</value>
            <value>file:///C:/mproject/workspace/framework_tmp/WebContent</value>
        </list>
    </property>
```

Since he would like to carry out deploy of the folder of deploy origin, developing, deploy of it is carried out from that besides the folder of jboss.

Please teach me how to succeed.

Comment: Incidentally description of web.xml is the following description. 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
</web-app>